# Remote BLOB Storage and FILESTREAM in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

I'm a SharePoint develop and I have just learned about remote blob feature in SQL Server 2008 that makes storing BLOBs more effecient.

My English's not good, somebody can tell me the difference between terms: FILESTREAM and Remote BLOB Storage. Is it work well in farm environment with SAN device.

Thanks so much.

Comment: do you mean Blob storage? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135733.aspx

Answer (score 2):

RBS with the Filestream Provider (which uses the underlying Filestream feature of SQL Server) will work very well in a farm environment with a SAN device.

There's a very good whitepaper [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/2/9521D8DA-5D3C-4817-BB9D-B5B1BD293365/SQL_Server_2008_R2_Remote_Blob_Storage.docx) which goes in to more detail.

Also, from my blog posting
[RBS & Filestream  Feature Comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrbs/archive/2009/11/18/sql-server-remote-blob-store-and-filestream-feature-comparison.aspx):

FILESTREAM and RBS are complementary approaches for storage and management of BLOBs.

- FILESTREAM provides a storage option that allows storage, efficient streaming and integrated management of large BLOBs in a SQL database by utilizing the underlying NTFS file system for BLOB storage/streaming. It offers fully transactional access and compatible operations as varbinary(max).
- RBS is a set of  standardized APIs that allow storage/retrieval of BLOBs outside of your main SQL database where a dedicated BLOB store is desirable for various reasons. This uses a provider model for plugging in any dedicated BLOB store that implements these RBS APIs.
- RBS has an out-of-the-box RBS FILESTREAM provider that allows a deployment to use a SQL Database (local or remote) as a dedicated BLOB store. This provider utilizes the FILESTREAM as the BLOB storage mechanism and ties the two technologies together.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx) Remote BLOB Storage is "an add-on feature pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2008" that USES the FILESTREAM feature of SQL 2008 R2 to store the files Sharepoint deals with.

FILESTREAM allows large binary blocks of data to be stored not in the database, but outside on a specifically dedicated folder keeping the actual database small (and fast). With FILESTREAM uploading this data is also faster since the data doesn't need to be partioned into SQL's 8KB Pages.

Note that backups still also backup this data. In fact, the whole thing is quite transparent to the connecting applications.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/sharepoint-2010-storing-documents-on-the-file-system-with-remote-blob-storage/) is a good article about RBS - overview and how to configure it with Filestream provider (it's about Sharepoint use case but it applies to many other scenarios)